# How to reduce to 10 V from a 44 V, 18 A solar panel supply?

Tags: dc, solar-cell, panel

I get 44 volts, 18 amps and 700 watts from two solar panels. I want to reduce approx 10 volts to run my inverter directly on solar panels instead of batteries during the daytime.

Comment: Do you mean your 700W DC-AC inverter has a 34V max input voltage? and do you have a MPPT controller? and what batteries ? you must have batteries to act as low ESR huge capacitors

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I Have tubular batteries. I dont have a MPPT controller.

Comment: You must provide the battery specs and should use a MPPT to optimize PV power.  What you want to do is ambiguous and poorly stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually simple. You can use a buck converter which is a switching power supply which can provide a low output voltage than the input voltage. 
But I would not recommend running an inverter directly from a solar panel. A good method will be to use a MPPT- Maximum Power Point Tracking controller.

Comment: I understand but buck converts are not that much robust. I made burn 3 buck converters. I need a robust circuit or method to handle such a high load.

Comment: You are mistaken Buck converters ARE robust. But I have burned out several of them too. The reason our circuits burned out was due to improper selection of switching devices. And If you totally don't wanna use them. then try a half bridge converter.

Comment: Friend, Plz tell me more about half bridge converter.

Comment: A half-bridge converter is a type of DC-DC converter that can supply an output voltage either higher or lower than the input voltage, using two transistors ,diodes and capacitors and a ferrite core transformer. Google is your best friend google it.